# Why Do I Have .APK Files in Every App Folder?

Tags: apk, delete

I have noticed .APK files in /Apps/[app name]/ directories and while I thought it supposed to be in /System/Apps/[app name]/ directory would it cause errors if I delete .APK files?

[image]

I am also wondering if Android no longer unpacks apps and reads straight from .APK files. According to screenshot below and comparing WeChat's .APK size with size shown in properties it seems like to be the case:

[image]

Comment: The APK files you mentioned are the very core of an app: if you delete them, the app will no longer result as installed, and will therefore be unable to be launched. This applies to system apps too.

Comment: Keep in mind that deleting those APK files will cause massive issues with reinstalling the apps. Always do a proper uninstall and delete the respective folders in `/data/data` as well as the records of the app in `/data/system/packages.list`.

Comment: @GiantTree It isn't necessary to manually delete the folder corresponding to the app in **/data/data/**. That's usually handled by Android itself after a reboot.